# Is there a type for template literals in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code which I use to create a JWT token and a cookie:

```
    public createCookie(token: Token): any {
        return `Authorization=${token.token}; HttpOnly; Max-Age=${token.expiresIn}`;
    }

    public createToken(user: UserInterface): Token {
        const expiresIn: number = 60 * 60; //1hr
        let signOptions: any = {
            expiresIn: expiresIn
        };
        let payload: TokenPayload = {
            _id: user.id
        };
        return { token: jwt.sign(payload, this.privKey, signOptions), expiresIn };   
    }
```

In the `createCookie` function, I had the return type initially set as `string` but I would not be able to access `Authorization`. For the time being, I have set the return type as `any` in order to work around the problem.

I would like to know, is there a type we can use to specify a template literal return type, instead of using `any`?

(Sorry, I literally just started using typescript only a few days ago and theres a lot I'm unsure of, thanks for understanding!)

Comment: Template strings are just strings. My guess is that you want to return a compound type with authorization, max-age and other properties as fields but then you'd need yet another method to pack the object into a string.

Comment: Template string types are a thing in TS. You can set the return type of the function to something along the lines of `Authorization=${string}; HttpOnly; Max-Age=${string}`. Can you share why you want the type? Maybe I can help you more?

Comment: docs- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html